# Autodesk.Viewing.UI.DataTable crushes other DataTables

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Are we not able to create multiple DataTables in one Forge Viewer ?

Two DataTables in different panels are working well if only one of them is open, however when the second panel is opened (when new DataTable is created) other DataTable crushes and writes `Loading data...` on it. It seems that, every kind of change made on one DataTable affects the other.

Is this situation normal ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid the current implementation of `DataTable` only supports a single instance at a time. I've been able to reproduce the same (or similar) issue - creating another instance of `Autodesk.Viewing.UI.DataTable` will show "Loading data..." forever. I will contact the engineering team to address this.

Comment: alright, thanks for the help. I'm hoping that we can see more functionalities on `DataTable` in the near future.

Comment: I agree, it's definitely a cool component to have at your disposal, but it still needs some love :) Cheers!

Comment: Exactly:) Cheers!